# Shell script not executing all commands in background

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script that reads files from an folder executes a python script with that file and then will move the file to another folder.
On server, the script works fine if running on foreground but if its triggered to run on background using & on logout it does not process python but moves all the files. I even tried adding disown for which it ran on logout for around 100 files post which it just moved the files and python was not triggered. This looks weird that a part of shell is executing.

Comment: Have you try nohup command? `nohup your-script > output.log 2> err.log &`

Comment: How is it triggered your script to run in background? if crontab is used, check the python command is found in the directories of PATH environment variable. The value of PATH variable in a shell session (foreground) is different than the one from crontab.

Comment: If I use nohup the file is not detected, says file not found in err.log file

Comment: I am running the script in background using & at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either

```
nohup your_script_file.sh &
```

Or you can use disown

```
disown your_script_file.sh &
```

also better than these

```
screen
```

Comment: nohup does not find the file, disown worked for 100 files then stopped, screen is working till now hope it works fine. Thanks...

Comment: Its working  with screen, trying to set cron job to run it with screen. Thanks for the help @Skynet